# How to list categories dynamically

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, nodes

Is there a way of creating lists of categories dynamically?

For instance, say I currently have 2 TVs on the site. If I then add a DVD player product, is it possible to automatically generate a DVD player link (in a block etc)?

I've been playing with Views as I thought it may have done the trick, but I've had no success. Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a View of Taxonomy terms would meet your needs.

If I wanted to create a block with a list of items tagged with term in the category "Electronics" then I would do something like this:

1. Create a View with the following options:

   - Show Taxonomy Terms
   - of type Electronics
   - sorted by [unsorted]
2. Check the "created a block" box.
3. Add terms "DVD player", "DSLR camera", and "LCD monitor" to my "Electronics" vocabulary.
4. Add the relevant terms to the relevant product pages
5. Enable the block

Now, if I start selling Zunes next month (hah) then I can add term "mp3 player" to the "electronics" vocabulary and it will show up in the list of electronics-related terms in my block.

Comment: I'm so glad it works for you. Don't forget you can upvote answers that you like.